# Change the Background image to none then change back to default background image

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

So I am making code about changing The backgound image like:

```
button3.BackgroundImage = default;
button3.BackgroundImage = null;
```

### But it does not work anyway. So the thing I need it to be is:

1. I Have 100 different buttons With Different images with **randomized names**
2. I Have checkbox1 Which will affect 100 buttons

- if **checked** Then All background Images in 100 buttons will be **None or null**
- if **not checked** then the 100 buttons will **restore the default background image**

3. Not using Some Method Like `button1.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"directory here");` because It will be so Long As I need to do it with **100 buttons**

if you know how then reply

Comment: You *do not* need 100 buttons to pick a random image

Comment: Try to give us a complete and reproducible codefragment to find out whatth eproblem is (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What GUI framework are you using?  [tag:winforms]?  [tag:wpf]?  [tag:unity3d]?  Something else?  Please [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question with the appropriate technology and, if possible, add a full [mcve] showing what you have tried so far and where you are stuck so you can receive an appropriate answer.  See: [ask].

Comment: Hi user19114315, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

C# is an OO language so you should use it that way. The obvious option here is to create your own custom class that encapsulates this functionality, e.g.

```cs
public class ButtonEx : Button
{
    private Image alternateBackgroundImage = null;

    public void ToggleBackgroundImage()
    {
        (alternateBackgroundImage, BackgroundImage) = (BackgroundImage, alternateBackgroundImage);
    }
}
```

You can then toggle all `Buttons` like so:

```cs
foreach (var btn in Controls.OfType<ButtonEx>)
{
    btn.ToggleBackgroundImage();
}
```